# How prominent are bible scholars that think that the "simplest reading" of some possibly polytheistic verses are the correct interpretation?

Tags: torah

Some verses in the Torah seem to contradict a purely monotheistic interpretation.

For example, deuteronomy 32:8

> When the Most High gave nations as their inheritance, when he
>   separated the human race, he set boundaries for the people according
>   to the number of the children of God.
>   But the LORD’s (Yahweh's) portion is his people, Jacob his allotted heritage.

http://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/32-8.htm
http://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/32-9.htm

A simple reading of those verses by themselves could be understood as God having many children each having his her own nation.

That may not be the only possible interpretation. However, I noticed that most translations have features:

1. Changing the word Yahweh to the Lord. Yahweh may be a name of a God instead of "the Lord". Changing Yahweh to "the Lord" means inserting interpretation.
2. Adding article the before Elyon. Elyon may be a name of another God instead of an epithet. The article "the" does not exist on the original text. The original text writes Elyon, instead of Ha Elyon.
3. Translating Bnei El to angelic beings, or heavenly host, instead of the natural children of El.
4. Masoretic edition uses Bnei Yisrael instead of Bnei El. Hence changing the text.

Here all those changes take a far more monotheistic tone than what could be translated from the text if one was not influenced by monotheistic presuppositions. I am not saying that monetheism is false. It's just that the original text doesn't seem to demand that meaning. What the text did say could be translated just as validly to not look very monotheistic at all.

> The Nephilim were on the earth in those days, and also afterward, when
>   the sons of God came in to the daughters of man and they bore children
>   to them. These were the mighty men who were of old, the men of renown.

http://biblehub.com/genesis/6-4.htm

There could be many ways to interpret that. However, a simple reading would mean God actually have sons that actually have biological compatibility with men and the Nephilims are God's grand children.

Again, many could interpret that differently. Some would think that the Nephilim are sons of children of Seth. However, that is quite a stretch. It could mean sons of rulers. That's also a stretch given that the text quite clearly says Bnei Ha Elohim, which literally means sons of the God (or sons of the gods?)

We think God couldn't have many grandchildren. However, the author of Torah may have thought differently. Maybe the author of Torah think that his god is like every other gods having children/family/hierarchy albeit very dysfunctional ones, like Zeus' family.

> and I have passed over through the land of Egypt during this night,
>   and have smitten every first-born in the land of Egypt, from man even
>   unto beast, and on all the gods of Egypt I do judgments; I am Jehovah.

http://biblehub.com/exodus/12-12.htm

A literal reading would suggest that the gods of Egypt were real enough to get punished by Hashem.

There could be other interpretation. But Elohim usually means gods and there is nothing in the text itself that suggest that it means judges rulers or something else. A monotheist may argue that it means judges because the Egyptian gods do not exist. We THINK the Egyptian gods do not exist. The author of the text may think differently.

**Main Question**

Getting back to Deuteronomy 32:8-9, with this passage as a primary example, are there any biblical scholars that interpret this passage and others in the Torah in polytheistic way? Preferably an established or published source?

If so, what were their assumption? Do they think the writer of those books were polytheistic or what?

Bonus: Any references to writings, communities or websites that also discuss this are appreciated.

Comment: Who gets to decide who is a serious biblical scholar and who is not?

Comment: Anyone that are serious enough is serious. It's a pretty low standard here.

Comment: Maybe I should use a different word. Prominent? Accepted? What? Why the downvote?

Comment: Jim, your question is written a way that assigns value judgements that ① many are likely to disagree with and ② raise concerns that you are trying to promote a position rather than ask a question.  (Using “filter” and “problematic” to describe the monotheism position and “natural” and “straightforward” to describe your own interpretation, for instance.) This is likely why it has garnered downvotes. If you have a real question, phrase it in a way that describes what you don’t understand without forcing us to accept your presuppositions in order to follow the question.

Comment: How should I rephrase the question? Basically I noticed that changing the word Yahweh to the Lord. Adding article the before Elyon and translating Bnei El into angelic beings and changing the Bnei El into Bnei Israel as unnatural.

Comment: 1) Your use of the term "natural interpretation" or "reading" is confusing. Maybe this term is common and understood a certain way in your circles, but it is not being used in a way that I'm familiar with anyone else on this site using. Is "natural" a literal linguistic reading? Within textual, cultural and historical context? A combination of those and/or others methods? It's just not clear.

Comment: 2) You come to conclusions within your question that don't simply bias possible answers, but preemptively reject their validity "A natural straightforward reading interpretation of that verse means God have many children..."And again you say "However, a natural interpretation would mean God actually have sons..." And "A natural interpretation would be that the gods of Egypt..." If you know these things to be the case, one might wonder why you're even posting a question?  I'm not objecting on any theological basis, I'm objecting to the discriminatory tone of the question toward possible answers

Comment: The text literally says that bnei El (sons of El) see that humans' daughters are pretty and came to them. What else could it possibly naturally mean? Do you have a more natural interpretation? You could say that bnei El could mean sons of Seth. I didn't see the name Seth on that verse

Comment: I shouldn't ask if there is any serious "scholars". The fact that wikipedia entry for Yahweh presume that the writer of Torah wasn't monotheist shows that there must have been plenty of scholars with that opinion. I should have asked how prevalent those scholars are

Comment: Google translate also add article "the"

> When the Most High nations divide people steadied limited number of
> people aged over Israel

https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%92%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%91%20%D7%92%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%83

This should be a start up project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Are there any serious biblical scholar that interpret bible this way?
```

Yes, quite a number of serious biblical scholars recognise that the Hebrew religion was polytheistic at least until the late monarchic period. They then become somewhat divided as to whether polytheism flourished right up until the time of the Babylonian Exile, or whether it became monolatrous (accepting the existence of multiple gods, but only worshipping one God) during the late monarchy. I provide two examples:

Leon R. Kass is a philosopher and expert on biblical Hebrew. In his book, *[The Beginning of Wisdom](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226425673): Reading Genesis*, he interprets the Book of Genesis (*Bereshit*) acording to the culture in which it was written. He recognises the existence of two distinct creation stories (Genesis 1:1-2:4a; 2:4b-25) and counsels that we must scrupulously avoid reading into the second story any facts or notions taken from the first, and vice versa.  He examines the Hebrew grammar in Genesis 20:13 and says that *'elohim*, usually translated as God (`When God sent me wandering from my father's house...`) ought properly be translated as 'the gods'. He also critically examines the story of Joseph in Egypt and finds a number of references, now treated throught the prism of monotheism, that could be read as polytheistic.

Mark S. Smith says, in *[The Early History of God](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080283972X)* says that Israel was polytheistic during the period of the Judges, although her major deities were not numerous in this period. He suggests (page 30) that religious devotion to Asherah perhaps lies behind Genesis 49:25. He says that 1 Kings 18:19 is an unambiguous reference to the goddess Asherah.

Comment: do they have forums? Where can I learn more about it?

Comment: @JimThio The only real forum if we can call it that, is in the various universities and seminaries in which they teach, often alongside other scholars or theologians who hold very different views. The best scholars publish papers and books.   One place where scholarly papers are regularly published online is https://www.academia.edu.  Here you can search for papers or refine your interest by 'Research Interest' (corr to our 'tags').

Comment: So I guess commoners like me can't just ask them questions. I noticed that wikipedia simply presume that the writer of the torah is polytheistic. You can see it on the entry for Yahweh

Answer (score 4):

I am going to answer your primary question...

> Are there any bible scholars that interpret first book of torah
>   naturally instead of through monotheism filter?

... based upon a challenge to your presuppositions.

All language is interpreted through a filter. Correct understanding of a text requires one to align to the "filter" the author of the text was using.

For example, if one says...

> The President did lie.

... to properly, or to use your term, "naturally" understand the statement, one has to at least know

1. What "President" is the speaker referring to (President of the United States, Argentina, or some other country?; President of General Motors, Microsoft, or some other company?, etc.), and
2. What is meant by "did lie" (did tell an untruth, did lie on a bed, or did [lie in state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lying_in_state)?)

So the context of a statement is part of the *necessary filter* for understanding the meaning of a text properly.

Therefore, if the "first book of torah" was *written within* a monotheistic context (and [if the traditional authorship of Moses is true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_authorship) [which I believe to be so], there is plenty of evidence within the Pentateuch that it was written from a monotheistic perspective), then interpreting it "naturally" ***is*** interpreting it through "monotheism," and **any other reading is "unnatural" to the text**.

So in your question you have at least potentially a false dichotomy between a "natural" and "monotheistic" interpretation (depending upon whether the monotheistic filter is the correct one to be reading the text by). The answer to the question is "no" if monotheism is the natural reading of its context; it is "yes" if monotheism is not the natural reading of its context.

Regarding specifically the passages you indicate as "problematic for monotheistic people," they are not problems at all to a monotheistic views, as any serious perusal of commentaries will show.

Other answers here have given some scholars who approach the text with the non-monotheistic filter for interpretation, showing that some do read the text through a different filter (whether that is natural or not still depends upon whether it is correct or not from the perspective of the author).

Comment: Changing Elyon into the Most High (adding article the), changing bnei El into angels. Changing bnei El into bnei Yisrael. Changing Yahweh into the LORD. All those changes are NOT natural. Without those changes it's hard to see how the texts are monotheistic.

Comment: You yourself said that you have a "filter". Then you yourself support aligning translation to your "filter". That is not natural. The natural translation of the president did lie, is that the president lied. Even google translate can do that. If after I translate that back the text says, "Obama lied", that is not a correct translation. Perhaps it means the same thing. perhaps, the president in the original text means Obama. But that is still not a natural translation. A natural translation of "the President did lie" is at most, "the President lied"

Comment: @JimThio: I said we all have a filter ("All language is interpreted through a filter"). You do, I do. Also, your question is about "interpretation" of a text, not "translation" of a text (though all translation involves some interpretation). I agree the translation would be "the president lied," but the _interpretation_ of what that phrase _means_ could be any of those I gave, depending upon the context of the statement. Do not confuse the terms translation and interpretation, as the latter is broader than the former.

Comment: Basically I want translation that's as unbiased as google translate and the simplest closest interpretation.

Comment: @JimThio: Google translate is not "unbiased," it is "mechanical." It cannot account for the best word choice among possible choices, because it cannot account for the _context_ of the statement. That is why a selected word in the translation section offers up other "options" to choose, and why there is a "Wrong?" selection to correct the mechanical filter. But there is still the issue that _interpretation_ is different from _translation_, and "closest interpretation" is not necessarily the same as "simplest reading" (i.e. "raining cats and dogs" [trans.] means "raining very hard" [inter.]).

Answer (score 1):

> **Question Restatement:** Are there scholars who affirm an understanding that the Sons of God had a "Divine, Godlike Nature?"

If I understood correctly, then:

> **Answer:** Yes. See Sons of God, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sons_of_God). 
>   "Claus Westermann claims that the text of Genesis 6 is based on an Ugaritic urtext. In Ugaritic, a cognate phrase is bn 'il. This may occur in the Ugaritic Baal Cycle., (ibid.)"

The idea that the Children of "the Most High" share the divine nature, is not foreign to Scripture.  This is evident in Psalms 82, John 3, Job 1:16.

Where the distinction lies is the difference in "Authority", rather than a difference in "Nature".

**NOTE:** As the Wikipedia article suggests, there is a lot of Textual Criticism concerns.  For more about finding out what the word for "God" is, consider the arguments found under the [Documentary Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentary_hypothesis).